# round function in excel . how to round to specific number?

Tags: excel, rounding

i have a question about rounding function in excel.my question is about rounding in excel without using VBA function.
if we assume that my value is `x.yy` i want to round value like this:

```
if  0<yy<.25 round to x;
if .25=<yy<5 round to x.25;
if .5=<yy<.75 round to x.5;
if .75=<yy<x+1 round to x+1;
```

hope my question make sense.

Comment: Simple: Add 0.25 and perform a standard round to nearest integer.

Comment: i am very new in excel . how i can perform a standard round to nearest integer ?

Comment: probably best to use Mod

Comment: i'm sorry. can you explain more?

Answer (score 1):

If your value is in `A2` try using this formula in `B2`

`=IF(MOD(A2,1)<0.75,FLOOR(A2,0.25),INT(A2)+1)`

That will round down to the previous multiple of 0.25 unless the decimal value is >= 0.75 in which case it rounds up to the next integer

Comment: thanks . but i didn't get right( base on my question ) answer by this . :(

Comment: I think this satisfies all the conditions in your question - can you give a specific example where it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=FLOOR(A1*4,1)/4
```

Comment: You can get the same result with `=FLOOR(A1,0.25)`....but according to the question `if .75=<yy<x+1 round to x+1;` - doesn't that mean some values will round up?